# How to create a Dropdown menu with Icons in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want different icons for different dropdown menu item , how can I achieve this ?

[Here is the Image which i want to implement in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmgE6.png)

Please Help

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

The Plugin

[dropdown_button2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2)

The data

```
List<Map> data = [
  {
  "name": "Name 1"
  "icon": Icons.alarm,
  },
  {
  "name": "Name 2"
  "icon": Icons.alarm,
  
  },
];
```

Implementation

```
late String selectedValue;

DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropdownButton2(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    items: data
                        .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: item['name'],
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(item['icon']),
                                  Text(
                                    item['name'],
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    value: selectedValue,
                  ),
                ),
```